# Dealing with incomplete time series data when using geeglm in R

Tags: r, generalized-estimating-equations

I have a time series data set (response variable measured 32 times during the year on 10 different subjects). At the time of measuring the response, also 3 environmental variables were measured.

I want to construct a model to be able 
1) to predict response based on the 3 environmental variables (to estimate the response variable continuously during the year)
and preferably, 
2) to assess which environmental variables were significant for the model

In my (limited) understanding, I should use something like:

```
 geeglm(response ~ var1*var2*var3,
                         data = data_set, 
                         id = subject,
                         corstr="ar1")
```

The problem is that in a few dates, data for a single subject is missing (the measurement was obviously not ok). The model still runs, but is the model now somehow matching data from different dates as if they were from the same date, as some subjects have fewer data points than the others? (The data was sorted by date of measurement and subject.) Time of the year has an effect on the response variable (mostly but not entirely through air temperature, which is one of the environmental variables), but not a linear or consistent one, so I am hesitant to include time as fixed effect. Am I correct that the waves argument would not solve this problem as it's still just giving the order of measurements?

Comment: What does `geeglm()` offer? We're not all R users here; if you wish specific advice on specific code that may be off-topic. What is the _waves argument_? I would expect time of year to be associated with periodic, i.e. seasonal, variability above all. That won't be linear, but more likely sinusoidal.